# Counting elements in an array -Performance-

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have this array : `var arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1 };` where I need to count the number of positives, negatives and zeros numbers.
I did it with `foreach` loop and with `Linq` and I tried to compare the performance between the two methods by using the `Stopwatch` here is my code:

```
        int pos = 0, neg = 0, zeros = 0;
        int p = 0, n = 0, z = 0;


        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        pos = arr.Sum(e => e > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        neg = arr.Sum(e => e < 0 ? 1 : 0);
        zeros = arr.Sum(e => e == 0 ? 1 : 0);

        sw.Stop();


        Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

        sw2.Start();

        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            if (item > 0) p++;
            else if (item < 0) n++;
            else z++;
        }

        sw2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed); //Elapsed=00:00:00.0008311
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed2={0}", sw2.Elapsed); //Elapsed2=00:00:00.0000028
```

The results showed me that the `foreach` loop where a lot better (28ms) than the `Linq` method (8311ms), So my question is why there is all this difference in performance?

I even tried to make three `foreach` loop, one to count the negatives, one to count the positives and the third to count the zeros, but the performance was still good than the Linq method!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So, what is your question about?

Comment: I believe it is because your array is very small. Linq creates the enumerator internally, and it takes some time. But if you have array with thousands of items, I think, Linq could be faster.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski why there is all this difference in performance?

Comment: You're creating 3 sequences with your linq methodS, vs 1 foreach loop

Comment: @Cid I did try with tree loops and it was still better than the Linq method

Comment: Also you can change it a little bit: pos = arr.Count(e => e > 0); neg = arr.Count(e => e < 0); zeros = arr.Count(e => e == 0);

Comment: 8311ms? Change your computer, it doesn´'t like linq :p. Granted that it will be slower, but that is way too much for a 5 element array. You are probably measuring the jitter and not warming up the benchmark correctly, but even that shouldn't add up to 8 seconds.

Comment: Using Benchmark.NET will provide more precise performance metrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's carry out *horse races* in a bit different manner:

```
private static string UnderTest(int size) {
  int pos = 0, neg = 0, zeros = 0;
  int p = 0, n = 0, z = 0;

  Random random = new Random(0);
  int[] arr = Enumerable
    .Range(0, size)
    .Select(x => random.Next(-1, 2))
    .ToArray();
  GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

  // Three Linq loops (expected to be 3 three times slower)
  pos = arr.Sum(e => e > 0 ? 1 : 0);    
  neg = arr.Sum(e => e < 0 ? 1 : 0);
  zeros = arr.Sum(e => e == 0 ? 1 : 0);

  sw.Stop();

  Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
  sw2.Start();

  // Just 1 loop 
  foreach (var item in arr) {
    if (item > 0) p++;
    else if (item < 0) n++;
    else z++;
  }

  sw2.Stop();

  return $"{sw.Elapsed} vs. {sw2.Elapsed} ratio: {((double)sw.Elapsed.Ticks) / sw2.Elapsed.Ticks:f3}";
}
```

Races for different array `size`s:

```
   int[] loops = new int[] {
    1000,
    10_000,
    100_000,
    1_000_000,
    10_000_000,
    100_000_000,
    1000,         // <- 1000 again
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, loops
    .Select(loop => $"loops: {loop,10} : {UnderTest(loop)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
loops:       1000 : 00:00:00.0006471 vs. 00:00:00.0000114 ratio: 56.763 // <- Warming up
loops:      10000 : 00:00:00.0003195 vs. 00:00:00.0001074 ratio: 2.975
loops:     100000 : 00:00:00.0037131 vs. 00:00:00.0010910 ratio: 3.403
loops:    1000000 : 00:00:00.0351574 vs. 00:00:00.0118858 ratio: 2.958
loops:   10000000 : 00:00:00.3729617 vs. 00:00:00.1198276 ratio: 3.112
loops:  100000000 : 00:00:03.7002508 vs. 00:00:01.1808595 ratio: 3.134
loops:       1000 : 00:00:00.0000322 vs. 00:00:00.0000099 ratio: 3.253 // <- Expected
```

What's going on: we have `3` *Linq* based loops (`3` calls for `Sum`), so Linq **3** times slower ( no surprise).
However we have a *huge outlier* at the *very first run* when system *loads assembly*, *compiles* IL code etc.
So you have a so called *warming up* effect.

Comment: Very nice answer. However, would you please explain why you are collecting garbage after creating the array `loops` ?

Comment: @Cid: Thank you! A better place for `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);` is just before races (within `UnderTest`): we don't want `GC` occasionally starts and disturbe the measurements

Comment: This makes sense, I'm not used to *manually* call GC, so collecting directly in the code would prevent the garbages to stack (heap, eh) up the street and the collector being called automatically ?

Comment: @Cid: We try to avoid unwanted processes (esp. garbage collecting which *stops the world*) to interfere. If we collect all the garbage (e.g., the array with millions of items) we can hope, that the following run will not be interrupted (say, in the middle of `foreach`).

Answer (score 1):

Foreach is a fancy representation for a simple for, iterating over the array once and counting all 3 values at once.

The sum creates a temporary variable(let us call it sum), and iterates over the array, calling the function you provided as argument, returning it's value and adding it to our temporary variable. This means, you call n functions, where n is the length of the array.

As you can probably guess from this, calling a function is way more expensive( in terms of clock cycles) than simply adding them up. You also do this 3 times, one for each arr.sum.

On top of all this, there's some overhead on(well any) functions, library or not, and since the array size isn't very big, that overhead WILL matter

Comment: There could also be some minor performance gains to be had regarding cache in the foreach, but they most likely are too small to matter in this example